# Many must with multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "egyik": {
                            "query": "piros alma"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "masik": {
                            "query": "piros alma"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It's not too beautiful, because the query parameter occured twice, therefore I tried to rewrite it with the multi_match syntax:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "piros alma",
                    "fields": [
                        "egyik",
                        "masik"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns more hits than the first. I tried operator, minimum_should_match modifiers, but not helps. How do I solve the same result with multi_match?

Comment: hi, have you checked my reply? was that of any help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all types of multi-match queries return a hit when the provided `query` matches any of the listed `field`s (see [Elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types)). Therefore, the reason why you have more hists with `multi_match` is that you can't enforce the same boolean condition you have with your first query. That said, I don't see anything wrong with repeating the same query parameter twice. If you want to generalise it a bit, you might want to consider using [Search Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-template.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default `operator` OR is used, which means query term can be present in any field, if you want query term to be present in all the fields then you can explicitly define `operator` field with `AND` value.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "piros alma",
                "fields": [
                    "egyik",
                    "masik"
                ],
                "operator":"and"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

To know more you can go through [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

Comment: Your suggestion is not the solution because it:

must to match word "piros" in field "egyik" AND field "masik", AND "alma" word must match in field "egyik" and field "masik".

I need 

word "piros" must match in field "egyik" OR field "masik"
AND
word "alma" must match in field "egyik" OR field "masik"

In other words: all query words must match in any fields.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found the solution:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "piros alma",
                    "fields": [
                        "egyik",
                        "masik"
                    ],
                    "type": "cross_fields",
                    "operator": "and"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Need the type and operator together.